# Rounding quotient from two different tables

Tags: sql

I am trying to `ROUND` to the nearest whole number the answer to

`(tableA.Col1-tableA.Col2) / (TablbeB.Col1)`

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I am working in a third party program. I need to configure it to what I want it to display, and it is all sql based.

Comment: Could u give us more info about the Table plz.  Code tag would clarify ur post.

Answer (score 0):

Most RDBMSs have a `round` function. It's hard to tell without the tables definitions, but assuming `col1` is the data's identifier, you could join on it:

```
SELECT ROUND((a.col1 - a.col2)/b.col1)
FROM   a
JOIN   b ON a.col1 - b.col1
```

Comment: This is what I would have to type if I were just doing a simple ROUND down to the nearest tenth from one table --> SELECT ROUND (column2, -1, 1) FROM tableA

Comment: I just don't know how to round a combination of operations using data from 2 diff tables.

Comment: Here's a simple way of what I'm trying to code: SELECT CASE WHEN (100 - ROUND(100/3)) < 73*01.0 AND Price>30 THEN 30-10 ELSE 30 FROM tableA JOIN table B ON tableA.col1=tableB.col1

Answer (score 0):

Some dbms products have `ROUND(val, p)`, where `p` is used to specify the wanted number of decimals in the result.

Combine with `CAST` to make sure the result data type is integer:

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND((1.0*tableA.Col1-tableA.Col2) / (TablbeB.Col1), 0) as integer)
FROM  tableA
    JOIN TablbeB ON tableA.id - TablbeB .id
```

(The multiplying with 1.0 is to make sure floating point arithmetics is used.)